# grep without stop or echo "Not found"

Tags: linux, grep

I have a bash file which contains some patterns I would like to search from a text file and write the whole line of matched pattern into a new file.

```
grep -P "^AAA," $score >> Pscores.txt &&
grep -P "^BBB," $score >> Pscores.txt &&
grep -P "^CCC," $score >> Pscores.txt &&
grep -P "^DDD," $score >> Pscores.txt &&
```

However, there is no BBB in the `$score`, then the bash has stopped. 
How can I change it to go through without stopping or just `echo BBB not found`

Comment: Just remove the trailing `&&`.

Comment: do you want to store them in order? Because otherwise you can just say `grep -E '^(AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD),'`.

Comment: @fedorqui that would also only print 1 line if it contained multiple matches instead of repeating the line once per match, which may or may not be desirable, idk. user.. - there's nothing in your regexp that would require the much slower perl-compatible regexp engine so lose the `-P`. Also, always quote your shell variables (google it).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be like below :

```
grep --option 'PATTERN' [FILENAME] >> output_file
```

Here we can introduce a ";" semi-colan which will terminates request by line by line and provides better understanding.

So, the grep commands in your case will be like:

```
grep -P "^CCC," $score >> Pscores.txt
```